# java eclipse debugging error

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have tried some of the existing solutions but it does not work.

I have two files/classes First.java (in which main is defined) and Second.java  where simple functions are defined.

```
**First.java:**

import java.util.*;

public class First 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
        Second s1 = new Second();
        s1.Hello(); 
    }
}
```

When I debug the above code in eclipse, it gives me error "source not found" on the line `Second s1 = new Second();`

However, this error occurs, if I click "step into". If I click "step over" on the aforementioned line, the error does not occur; and if click on "step into" in subsequent steps, the error does not occur again, and the execution successfully enters into the second file "Second.java".

So my question is, Is there a way that I can enter the constructor of the "Second.java" without stepping over it?

How to set the source path.

Second.java class:

```
public class Second 
{
    int a;
    public Second()
    {
        this.a=100;
    }

     public void Hello()
     {
         System.out.println("hello how are you");
     }

     public int GetResult()
     {
        return a; 
     }


}
```

Comment: Where is Second.java defined exactly? Is it in another Jar file? Another project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you 'step into' the line when the Second object is created, it is asking the classloader to load the Second class. Since you probably do not have eclipse setup to point to the location of the java sources, eclipse does not know where the java source code is on your machine for all the files the vm uses to load the class, including java.lang.ClassLoader, and eclipse shows you the 'Source not found' page.

You can:

1. Move the break point from the line `Second s1 = new Second();` in First.java to `public Second()` in Second.java. Then when you debug, you should hit the break point *after* the Second object has been loaded by the VM and you should be able to debug the constructor as it is being instanciated.
2. When you 'step into' the break point at the line `Second s1 = new Second();` and get the source not found page, immediately 'step return' and then press 'step into' again, which should take you to the constructor of the Second class.
3. Click on attach source, and browse to the directory of the java source files. They are usually included with the JDK download and are located in a file called src.zip in the installation folder of your VM (for the Sun VM).

Answer (score 0):

Source not found usually means that Eclipse can't find the required files. Is Second.java in your project? The best thing is to make a package such as me.russjr08.projects. That way Eclipse can search through the package (Assuming all of the correct files are there) and find the class / java files you want to use.

IIRC Another solution is to include Second.java in your src folder